# Tinting and shading effects in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

How to provide these kind of tinting and shading effects to round shaped buttons in CSS?[image]

Comment: please provide the CSS which you have tried so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Tip: take a look at CSS's [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) function.

Comment: Use a pseudo element, give it a white background, same shape and then use `opacity` to control transparency. For any other suggestion, provide a working code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of the buttons can be done with `border-radius` applied on a regular `button` element and their colours are just a `linear-gradient` background. In the *shade* version another gradient is applied over the base gradient with a `::before` pseudoelement

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/erOzew)

---

**Markup**

```
<button class="green">GO</button>
<button class="green shade">GO</button>
<button class="green disabled">GO</button>

<button class="blue">Back</button>
<button class="blue shade">Back</button>
<button class="blue disabled">Back</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.green { background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #18c99d, #12977c) }
.blue { background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #707b98, #283b6b) }

.shade::before { 
  content: "";
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: inherit;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 25, .25) 
}

.disabled { 
  opacity: .3; 
  cursor: not-allowed; 
}
```

---

**Result**

[image]

Comment: ...... Thanks a lot for your solution

Answer (score 0):

**in Html:**

```
<button class="button">Try me</button>
```

**in Css:**

```
.button{
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
   border: none;
   color: white;
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**Explain:**

```
border-radius: 50%; //make the circle shape

 opacity: 0.5;  // make the shading effect
```

Comment: the 0.5 of `opacity` is only for example u can try more number between 0 to 1

Comment: Thanks!!....................

Comment: @EatingCode I really appreciate if you up vote

Comment: Even though I have up voted, that will not show, as I am new member to stack overflow and don't have enough reputation.

Comment: fine :) happy to help